# Join original np array with resulting np array in a form of dictionary? multidimensional array? etc?

Tags: python

I have a numpy array with hex data which I am converting to decimals which prints a  np array. However, what I need as a final output is a hex code and corresponding decimal number. I guess the solutions could be, to save it as a dictionary, concatenate the original `hek` with resulting `s` as the multidimensional array and then, save it as `df`. Any ideas?

```
hek = ['45da', '45db', '45dc']
lst = []
for i in hek:
    s = int(i, 16)
    lst.append(s)
print(lst)
```

[image]

Comment: Well, the final output should be a dataframe with two colums: 'hek' and 'decimal' where the values from the hek np array will go and decimals with the s results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **list comprehension**:

```
pd.DataFrame({"hek": hek, "decimals": [int(i, 16) for i in hek]})
```

Illustration:

```
# The input data
hek = ['45da', '45db', '45dc']

# Convert hek elements to integer
int_column = [int(i, 16) for i in hek]
print(int_column)
# [17882, 17883, 17884]

# Build dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"hek": hek, "int": int_column })
print(df)
#     hek    int
# 0  45da  17882
# 1  45db  17883
# 2  45dc  17884
```

Other way in pandas with the `int` conversion using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
# Build dataframe from hek list
df = pd.DataFrame({"hek": hek})
# Apply the conversion to the hek column
df["decimals"] = df.hek.apply(lambda x: int(x, 16))
print(df)
#     hek    int
# 0  45da  17882
# 1  45db  17883
# 2  45dc  17884
```

Comment: Glad to help you. Feel free to accept the answer if that solved your problem. Happy coding !

Comment: Sure, was waiting for 5 min to pass as per Stack rules.